# AndroidPlot : setting the labels on the X-axis

Tags: android, androidplot

With the AndroidPlot website being down, I'm kind of stuck on this issue. Several similar questions have been asked, but none of them were properly answered, so here I go.

I would like to know how I can relabel my X-axis. For example, if I want to plot values about monthly data, I would plot it like `(1, 82)` for Januari, `(2,67)` for Februari , and so on. Afterwards, I want to change the X-labels from `[1, 2, 3, ...]` to `x_labels = ["Januari", "Februari", ...]`. How can I do this?

Oh and please provide an answer for which `x_labels` can be anything (in case there is some specific method for monthly labels, you never know).

Anyone who could help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out myself:

```
this.getGraphWidget().setDomainValueFormat(new GraphXLabelFormat());

// ...

private class GraphXLabelFormat extends Format {

    private static LABELS = ["Label 1", "Label 2", "Label 3"];

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(Object object, StringBuffer buffer, FieldPosition field) {
        int parsedInt = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(object.toString()));
        String labelString = = LABELS[parsedInt];

        buffer.append(labelString);
        return buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public Object parseObject(String string, ParsePosition position) {
        return java.util.Arrays.asList(LABELS).indexOf(string);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create the plot? I cannot add a string to array to the series

Comment: @Aegonis: thank you for the help, I got the hint from your answer for how to do that.

Comment: `setDomainValueFormat` method doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

I used the code written by @Aegonis and make complete code for setting `String` labels.

I used these 3 array in my case.

```
Number[] yValues = {1, 3, 2 ,7 ,6};
Number[] xValues = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

final String[] xLabels = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"};
```

Now the code for the class which extends `Format` provided by @Aegonis.

```
class GraphXLabelFormat extends Format {

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(Object arg0, StringBuffer arg1, FieldPosition arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int parsedInt = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(arg0.toString()));
        Log.d("test", parsedInt + " " + arg1 + " " + arg2);
        String labelString = xLabels[parsedInt];
        arg1.append(labelString);
        return arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object parseObject(String arg0, ParsePosition arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return java.util.Arrays.asList(xLabels).indexOf(arg0);
    }
}
```

Now the code from `onCreate` method.

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);

plot.setDomainLabel("TestDomain");
plot.setRangeLabel("TestRange");
plot.setTitle("Height/Weight");

//set domain labels as string [x-axis]
plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainValueFormat(new GraphXLabelFormat());

XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(Arrays.asList(xValues), Arrays.asList(yValues), "Line");

plot.addSeries(series, new LineAndPointFormatter());
```

Comment: `setDomainValueFormat` method doesn't exist

Comment: @NickUnuchek maybe it's removed, this is 7 years old, I haven't checked recently :)